# Can I fit different regression models using mapply?

Tags: r, mapping, eval, lapply

I'm trying to see if I can fit multiple regression models using the mapply function on the iris dataset.

I start by defining my regression model:

```
reg<-function(dependent,independent){lm(eval(paste0(dependent,"~",independent,",data=iris")))}
```

I then define my vectors of dependent and independent variables:

```
dependent<-c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")
independent<-c("Sepal.Width","Sepal.Length")
```

Finally I try to apply the mapply function:

```
models_reg<-mapply(reg,dependent,independent)
```

I get an error message, however, claiming that:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:25: unexpected ','
1: Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,
```

Is it possible to achieve my objective (fitting different regression models using mapply) and in that case, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to evaluate a string here. You can pass formula as string in `lm` :

```
reg<- function(dependent,independent) {
   lm(paste0(dependent,"~",independent),data=iris)
}
```

Another way to construct the formula is using `reformulate` :

```
reg<-function(dependent,independent) {
  lm(reformulate(independent, dependent),data=iris)
}
```

Now you can call using `Map` :

```
Map(reg, dependent, independent)

#$Sepal.Length

#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate(independent, dependent), data = iris)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#     6.5262      -0.2234  


#$Sepal.Width

#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate(independent, dependent), data = iris)

#Coefficients:
# (Intercept)  Sepal.Length  
#     3.41895      -0.06188
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But why doesn't mapply work here, I get a list with 24 elements?

Comment: `mapply` would work with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`. `mapply(reg, dependent, independent, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`. Read `?mapply` to know the details.